# memcachedを使ったセッション管理

Tags: php, memcached

サーバー2台をロードバランシングしているので、memcachedを使ってsession管理をしようとしています。

全てのページに以下のコードを追加しているのですが、非常に読み込みが重いです、、。

どのように変更すればいいでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
<?php
$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer("ipアドレス", 11211);
if(empty($_SESSION["user"])){
  if($mc->get("id")){
    $_SESSION["user"]["id"] = $mc->get("id");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

memcachedなら、標準でセッションをmemcacheに管理する機能が付いています。
http://php.net/manual/ja/memcached.sessions.php